# jQuery $.when() where one of its parameters comes via an asynchronous "Deferred pipe"

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred, decoupling

One use of jQuery's `Deferred` system is with the `$.when()` function. It takes a variable number of `Promise's and will do something when they all`resolve`(or when the first`reject`s.)

So if you wanted to operated on two Ajax `JSON` queries for instance you could do:

```
var funkyPromise = $.getJSON('http://funky.json.service.com');
var awesomePromise = $.getJSON('http://awesome.json.service.com');

$.when(funkyPromise, awesomePromise).then(function() {
  /* do something amazing with the two objects */
}, function() {
  /* at least one of the services failed this time */
});
```

Another thing you can do with jQuery's `Deferred` system is to make data pipelines by "chaining" the data from one `Deferred` through another using the `pipe` method before ultimately using it:

```
$.getJSON('http://funky.json.service.com')
  .pipe(funkytoFunkier);
}).done(function(funkyData) {
    /* we now have a funkier version of what the web service gave us */
});
```

Everything wonderfully asynchronous and decoupled.

But what happens if I want to use `$.when()` on two asynchronous `Promise`s but we don't have one of them yet because it will come through a `pipe` asynchronously?

```
var funkyPromise = $.getJSON('http://funky.json.service.com');
var awesomePromise = $.getJSON('http://awesome.json.service.com');

// run "funky" through an asynchronous "pipe" to get "funkier"
//
// ... but ... how ??

$.when(funkyier, awesome).then(function() {
  /* do something amazing with the two objects */
}, function() {
  /* at least one of the services failed this time */
});
```

So what goes in the middle section?

- Is it blindingly obvious and I just can't see it?
- Is it possible but something quite subtle and tricky?
- Would some new "inverted" equivalent of `pipe()` or `$.when()` etc make it easier?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to nest these deferred calls?

Comment: @DrColossos: For this the problem getting my head around it, so for some use cases nesting would be an option, there may also be use cases where it's not so I want to understand it without nesting... if it's possible that is (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pipe()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) returns a new promise that will be resolved when the pipe is resolved, so you only have to write:

```
var funkyPromise = $.getJSON('http://funky.json.service.com');
var awesomePromise = $.getJSON('http://awesome.json.service.com');

$.when(funkyPromise.pipe(funkytoFunkier), awesomePromise).then(function() {
  /* do something amazing with the two objects */
}, function() {
  /* at least one of the services failed this time */
});
```

Note that, starting with jQuery 1.8, `then()` does the same thing as `pipe()`, so the two methods are basically interchangeable.

Comment: Yes you're completely right. I'd been overthinking this for weeks actually (because I didn't fully grok all the Deferred / asynchronous / decoupling issues I suppose) but after writing it all down clearly then walking up and down the beach for a while mulling it over I came to the same conclusion that it's utterly trivial. Test code coming in an answer...

Answer (score 1):

[@Frédéric Hamidi knew the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12283911/527702) but I had to figure it out `(-:` Here's a trivial example I got working after Frédéric wrote his answer but before I read it:

[>> jsFiddle ...](http://jsfiddle.net/hippietrail/Jxj7n/1/)

```
function foo() {
    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000),
        d = $.Deferred();

    console.log('foo starting: ' + time);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('foo resolving');
        d.resolve(time);
    }, time);

    return d.promise();
}

function bar() {
    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
        d = $.Deferred();

    console.log('bar starting: ' + time);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('bar resolving');
        d.resolve(time);
    }, time);

    return d.promise();
}

function baz(previousTime) {
    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
        d = $.Deferred();

    console.log('baz starting: ' + time);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('baz resolving');
        d.resolve(previousTime + ' + ' + time + ' = ' + (previousTime + time));
    }, time);

    return d.promise();
}

$.when(foo(), bar().pipe(baz))
    .then(function(foo, barBaz) {
        console.log('when OK', [foo, barBaz]);
    });​
```